# How to convert promise result into json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-promise

I'm trying to use axios to fetch json from an external API and serve it to my frontend. When I go to the route I created I see the json just fine. However, when I pass it to the frontend by hitting the end point and I console log to see if it works, I get this: [frontend console log of promise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7JTb.jpg)

This is my backend code to fetch the external API:

```
app.get('/entertainment', async (req,res) => {

 const respy = await axios.get(process.env.API_URL, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`
    }
  })
  .then((resp) =>  res.send(resp.data))
  .catch(e => console.log(e, "SOME ERROR"))
})
```

Frontend portion:

```
componentDidMount(){
     fetch('http://localhost:8000/entertainment').then((res) => {
       this.setState({
         projectData: res.json()
       })
     }).then(res => {
      console.log(this.state.projectData)
     })
   }
```

How do I resolve this promise?  I thought the .then or the await would resolve it.

Comment: Where do you get an unresolved promise?

Comment: you are probably using 'fetch' to make the network request. Just do this 'fetch('api url').then(res => res.json()).then(json => //display it in ur frontend); hope it works, the promise is getting resolved.

Comment: i.e. the "error" is in the frontend code, but you've shown the backend code

Comment: @Bravo just added the frontend

Comment: @VLAZ on the frontend where I try to console log the data

Comment: @NikeLepz I'm using axios and I tried to convert it to fetch but it doesnt work.

Comment: res.json returns a promise too if documentation is accurate

Comment: res.json doesn't return the data, but the promise which resolves with your data. See https://javascript.info/fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging the promise into your console. And the promise is getting resolved by the way, as you can see in the screenshot. It is being resolved with the following object:

```
{
  businesses: [...],
  region: [...],
   total
}
```

You're just not doing anything with it. Consider doing the following:

**make request to the api on your frontend and do log the data the fetch resolves with in the console**

```
fetch(YOUR_SERVER_URL).then((res) => res.json()).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Making a change to the code you've included in the edit:

```
componentDidMount(){
     fetch('http://localhost:8000/entertainment').then((res) => res.json()).then(data => {
       console.log(data)
       this.setState({
         projectData: data
       })
     })
   }
```